# Biospans from String and Dictionary of Start and End Tokens for NLP Preprocessing

Tags: python, nlp, data-processing

Suppose I have a simple sentence and a dictionary of which has 2 lists as start and end where start has the starting token and end has the ending token for each BIO Span and I want to create the BIO tags for the sentence where B denotes Beginning, I Inside and O Outside which is a pretty well used concept for data preprocessing in NLP how can I do it?

For instance suppose the input sentence is `"I like to play soccer while he likes to run"` and the dictionary of tokens is `{'start': [0, 6], 'end': [3, 9]}` then the expected output is `B I I I O O B I I I`

You can assume the spans don't overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function does exactly this-

```
def spanbio(sent, toks):
    """
    Format:
    sent - Sentence - Simple String
    toks - Spans as Dictionary - Ex. {'start': [0, 13, 22], 'end': [4, 19, 27]}
    """
    samplespanstart = toks['start']
    samplespanend = toks['end'].copy()
    print("preadd", samplespanstart,samplespanend)
    for i in range(len(samplespanend)):
        samplespanend[i] = samplespanend[i] + 1
    ls = ['O']*len(sent.split())
    print(sent.split())
    print("lslen", len(ls))
    for i, j in zip(samplespanstart,samplespanend):
        print(i,j)
        for k in range(i,j):
            ls[k] = 'B'
    for i in range(1,len(ls)):
        if (ls[i-1] == 'B' and ls[i] == 'B'):
            ls[i] = 'I'
        elif (ls[i-1] == 'I' and ls[i] == 'B'):
            ls[i] = 'I'
    return ' '.join(ls)
```

Driver Code to Run it -

```
sent = "I like to play soccer while he likes to run"
toks = {'start': [0, 6], 'end': [3, 9]}
print(spanbio(sent, toks))
```

Output -

```
B I I I O O B I I I
```